# Haar-measure in KAK decomposition of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: measure-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, haar-measure

I would like to know if there is any way to calculate the Haar-measure of the Lie group $ SL (2, \mathbb{R}) $ with respect to the $ KAK $-decomposition, where:

for each $ g \in SL (2, \mathbb{R}) $, there are $ k_1, k_2, a \in GL (2, \mathbb{R}) $ such that $ g = k_1 a k_2 $ for

$ k_i = \left (\begin{array}{cc} cos (\theta_i) & -sin (\theta_i) \\ sin (\theta_i) & cos (\theta_i) \end{array} \right) $ for $ i = 1,2 $ and $\theta_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

$ a = \left (\begin{array}{cc} \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & \alpha^{- 1} \end{array} \right) $ for $ \alpha \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0} $.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by "calculate with respect to..." But you can use the fact that $SL(2,R)/K$ is naturally diffeomorphic to the upper half-plane $H^2$ and acts on it isometrically. Hence, you can take the (invariant) hyperbolic measure $y^{-2}dxdy$ and lift it to $SL(2,R)$. Or you may prefer to use the unit disk model.

Comment: @MoisheKohan 
I know that $ SL (2, \mathbb{R}) $ has the $ KAK $-decomposition and the $ KAN $-decomposition, so I emphasize that I am interested in the $ KAK $-decomposition

Comment: Then work in the unit disk model as more suitable (via polar coordinates).